# Induction in conducting spherical shells

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

Figure shows three concentric shells. Charge $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are given to the innermost and outer most shell respectively. [image: the problem]

I tried to find the charge on the outer surface of outer most surface by assuming that the middle earthed shell takes up charge $q'$ from the earth. This is how I have proceeded. 
[image: my try]

But the answer that I should be getting is different. Can someone please explain me the flaws in my logic?

Comment: Id love to be corrected

Comment: I await your reply Experts

Answer (score -1):

The first equation is correct, giving $$q' = -\frac{b}{c}Q_2\ .$$ But the second one is incorrect. The net charge on the exterior of the outer shell is $Q_2 + q'$.
$Q_1$ has no role to play there. I'll leave it to you to justify why $Q_1$ plays no role there.

Comment: try to prove evrything again from scratch, and you should see your mistake.

Comment: Exactly I figured out that the correct answer would be achieved it I ignore the role of $Q_1$ but why? It comes at the outer surface of outer most shell so it should have a contribution shouldn't it?

Comment: no, Q1 is completely shielded by the induced charges on the inner surface of the middle  shell

Comment: Sorry but that didn't clear my doubt. Could you possibly draw up a diagram or something to let me get it better?

Answer (score -1):

Since the middle shell is grounded, its potential is zero and therefore there won't be any field emanating from it outside and possibly affecting the distribution of charges on the outer shell.

Hence, the charge on the outer surface of the outer shell will be Q2.

The middle shell will take some charge from the earth, but that charge will be used to kill the field outside the middle shell.